# LilyPond: How do I align markup text with #"scripts.segno"?

Tags: lilypond, repeats

At the end of my score, I'd like to have a "Da Capo al Segno", with a nice symbol for segno.

I'm almost there:

```
DC = {
  \once \override Score.RehearsalMark #'break-visibility = #end-of-line-visible
  \once \override Score.RehearsalMark #'self-alignment-X = #RIGHT
  \mark \markup { "D.C. al " \tiny \musicglyph #"scripts.segno" }
}
```

But the segno is not aligned with the text:

[image: Not aligned segno]

How can I make that better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Can't segno satisfaction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nrIPxlFzDi0)...

```
% LilyPond engraving system - http://www.lilypond.org/
\version "2.18.0"

% There exists U+1D10B though lilypond 2.18.2 renders \char ##x1D10B as a
% boxed question mark for me. so...

DC = {
  \once \override Score.RehearsalMark #'break-visibility = #end-of-line-visible
  \once \override Score.RehearsalMark #'self-alignment-X = #RIGHT

  % option 1, move the segno up...
  %\mark \markup { "D.C. al " \raise #1.1 { \tiny \musicglyph #"scripts.segno" } }

  % ... or option 2, move the text down
  \mark \markup {
    \general-align #Y #-1.0 { "D.C. al " \tiny \musicglyph #"scripts.segno" } }
}

bbbb = {
 \tempo 4=96
 bes1~bes~bes~bes~bes~bes~bes\ppp\DC
 \bar "|."
}

\score {
  \new Staff << \bbbb >>
  \layout { }
}
```

Neither of these seem very satisfying, as they do not get to the root as to why that segno is seemingly disconnected from the surrounding markup. :/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, *D.C. al Segno* certainly isn't a "normal" repeat sign.

This is because segni are usually jumped to backwards, from a *D.S.* (like *D.C.*).  And segni aren't usually used as ending markers.  These are marked with a final barline and *Fine* (even when in the middle of a piece).

---

With LilyPond v2.23, there comes some new syntax for repeat structures:  *Da Capo*, *Dal Segno*, *... al Fine*, etc. as seen on this page of the documentation:  [1.4.1 Long repeats](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/long-repeats)

This avoids the need for designing your own markup functions, but unfortunately is not so easy to customise.

```
\version "2.23.6"

{
    \repeat segno 2 {
        a'1 |
        \volta 2 { \fine }
        a'1 |
        \section
    }   
}
    
{
    a'1 |
    \repeat segno 2 {
        b'1 |
        \volta 2 { \fine }
        c''1 |
        \section
    }   
}
```

[image: image of above code, showing D.C. al Fine and D.S. al Fine]